# Validation not working on click of submit button but after submit proccess does, why so?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a validation on a text field. After a submit page button is pressed, I want the validations to check the code below and return a plsql text if it fails. Once the validation returns null(as in no issue) an after submit proccess should occur. The issue is, the after submit proccess still occurs and the validations are only producing >> ELSE RETURN 'Invalid email address'; rather than any of the other e.g. invalid email address if there's no text in the field. Oh an also I have a server side condition on the field to work when the button is clicked.

Help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: thanks for editing. I did have the BEGIN in it before I just forgot to add it to this post. The issue is still ongoing.

```
BEGIN

IF (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2, '@gmail.com') > 0)  THEN RETURN NULL;
ELSIF (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2,'@hotmail.com) > 0) THEN RETURN NULL;
ELSIF (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2,'@yahoo.com') > 0)THEN RETURN NULL;

ELSIF (:P101_NEW_2 = NULL) THEN RETURN 'Input Email Address';
ELSIF (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2, '@gmail.com') < 1) OR (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2,'@hotmail.com') < 1) OR (INSTR(:P101_NEW_2,'@gmail.com') < 1) THEN RETURN 'Input Email Address';
ELSE RETURN 'Invalid email address';

END IF;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: It's only returning the else statement for all validations with plsql expression returning text even when the field is null etc. o.O

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved it. It's validation with PL/SQL Function (returning text). I did not create a function as you can see from the above code. I'll create a function and include that code and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Still producing the result of else and skipping the other returns.

Comment: it's considered a function if it has a RETURN statement.

Answer (score 0):

Email address validations typically validate the format, but that's up to you.

```
not REGEXP_LIKE(:P1_EMAIL, '^[^.]([a-zA-Z0-9_''\+\.\-]+)[^.]@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$')
```

Validations aim for true/null, so if there is a problem then depending on the type it will return false or a message to display.

If you compare `:P1_EMAIL = null`, it will always return false. Nothing is ever = null. It should be `:P1_EMAIL is null`

Your penultimate condition might as well be `:P1_EMAIL is not null`, since you've checked content and null-ness.

You only need begin/end if you have declare or exception sections.

And you will **rarely** need a commit in APEX.